# How to save a string too large for a column?

Tags: oracle, grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I have this Domain Class:

```
class Jobs {

String query

static constraints = {
    query(maxSize: 63760)
    query type: "text"
}

 static mapping = {
//And I tried all this:
// sqlType: "char", length:63760
// query sqlType: DbSupport.bigStringType
// table 'HYPJobs'
//query sqlType: "text"
//query(nullable: true, maxSize: 64000)
// query type:'materialized_clob',sqlType: "clob"
}

}
```

but When I run it I still having this error:

ORA-12899: value too large for column "Myproject"."JOBS"."QUERY" (actual: 1395, maximum: 255)

Anyone ???

Comment: did you try static mapping = { query type: 'text' }?

Comment: yes! I did, all the possible combination in my desperation!

Comment: What's your dbCreate setting in your DataSource.groovy?

Comment: Also, what's the schema on the table in the DB state the column type as?

Comment: the schema is varchar(63760);
and i have a connection to DataSource.groovy in Oracle, but that value comes from TeraData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
class Jobs {

  String query

  static constraints = {
    query maxSize: 63760 // remove this unless you really want to limit the size to 63760
  }

  static mapping = {
    query type: 'text'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, the actual table column is `varchar2(255)` and you're trying to insert a value with 1395 characters.

You will need to increase the column length in the DB if you want longer values. You can't go beyond 4k with a `varchar2` column though (until 12c anyway); if you actually need values up to 64k then you'll need to make the column a `clob` instead. Just changing the declaration in Groovy (or wherever, I'm not sure where the `varchar(63760)` is!) won't affect the size of the column in the database itself.